# What is pointy things in Git commits history in VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

[image: screenshot]

I need to demonstrate a complicated git flow. So i checked examples. But couldn't understand the pointy things. What is that?

Comment: It is from VSTS.

Comment: It means that the previous commit is way back and does not fit on the page timeline-wise. You can probably click on it to scroll/jump there.

Comment: Ohh. Sorry i  realised now. Can @Thilo  post as answer?

Comment: Here is a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/05/10/announcing-git-graph-and-advanced-filters-to-visualize-commit-history/) about the graphs if you'd like to read more about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Thilo's comment:

> It means that the previous commit is way back and does not fit on the page timeline-wise. You can probably click on it to scroll/jump there.